# defining several functions in a loop and assigning them accordingly, in python

Tags: python, function

For defining several functions in a loop I have no problem using the code:

```
U=[]
for i in range(100):
    U.append(function('U_%s' %i, x))
```

but if I want to also assign some rules to these functions, again from within a loop, then I don't know how to accomplish this, always receiving errors like these: "**SyntaxError: can't assign to operator**", "**SyntaxError: can't assign to function call**", "**TypeError: 'list' object is not callable**" and etc. depending on how that I have so far tried to assign to the functions in a loop. I want to assign a power series in x to each function with the coefficients of the power series being different for different functions.

Any idea how to resolve this?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
U=[]
for i in range(100):
    coeffs = (1, 2, 3)
    def func(x):
        return coeffs[0] + x*coeffs[1] + x*x*coeffs[2]
    U.append(func)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good, bt let me time if I can modify it to fit my needs, I want it to give different power series to different functions, hopefully it can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to share my practice. The below works fine.

```
def func(x):
    ''''''
    coeffs = (1, 2, 3)
    return coeffs[0] + x*coeffs[1] + x*x*coeffs[2]

def main():
    ''''''
    U=[]
    for i in range(100):
        U.append(func(i))
    print U

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is very much like the other answer from @Ilimo-Euro, right?

Comment: No, this answer is very different. In this answer, func is evaluated for every value from 0 to 99, and the returned values stored in U. In the one from @limo-Euro, you get 100 function call references stored in U, each with the arguments `(1,2,3)`, but none of the func references has actually been called. You would need to follow up with something like `vals = [f() for f in U]`.